# Python Pandas Dataframe: Using Values in Column to Create New Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've searched several books and sites and I can't find anything that quite matches what I'm trying to do.  I would like to create itemized lists from a dataframe and reconfigure the data like so:

```
      A     B                A     B     C     D  
0     1     aa          0    1     aa  
1     2     bb          1    2     bb  
2     3     bb          2    3     bb    aa  
3     3     aa     --\  3    4     aa    bb    dd  
4     4     aa     --/  4    5     cc  
5     4     bb  
6     4     dd  
7     5     cc
```

I've experimented with grouping, stacking, unstacking, etc. but nothing that I've attempted has produced the desired result.  If it's not obvious, I'm very new to python and a solution would be great but an understanding of the process I need to follow would be perfect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas you can query all results e.g. where A=4.

A crude but working method would be to iterate through the various index values and gather all 'like' results into a numpy array and convert this into a new dataframe.

Pseudo code to demonstrate my example: 
(will need rewriting to actually work)

```
l= [0]*df['A'].max() 
for item in xrange(df['A'].max() ):
    l[item] = df.loc[df['A'].isin(item)]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
# or something of the sort
```

I hope that helps.

Update from comments:

```
animal_list=[]

for animal in ['cat','dog'...]:
    newdf=df[[x.is('%s'%animal) for x in df['A']]]

    body=[animal]    
    for item in newdf['B']
        body.append(item)

    animal_list.append(body)

df=pandas.DataFrame(animal_list)
```

Comment: thanks user2589273...I'm afraid I wasn't specific enough in my example.  The real data in both columns consists of strings and when I try this, it complains about trying to multiply strings.  To help me understand, what is the first line doing?

Comment: try   df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)   to convert strings into floats for your dataframe.  Or more specifically df['A'] = df['A'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True). My first line is creating an empty array of zeroes, as I do not know if you a values are sequential or have gaps...

Comment: Also I have realised my use of max is likely to be incorrect - editing answer now

Comment: The data is all strings, not numbers represented as strings...a better example would be:

Comment: Well, I would show you but the formatting doesn't show up right and I can't post a picture but...imagine the numbers of column A are animals and the content of column B is features such as horse-hooves, horse-long tail, monkey-long tail, etc.  I want to collect all animal features behind the animal in a single row.  And thanks very much for the explanation...it makes it much easier to understand the why.

Comment: @Velcro see new answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method that will work with strings. Customize the column naming as per needs.

```
data =  {'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5],
         'B': ['aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'dd', 'cc']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

maxlen = df.A.value_counts().values[0]  # this helps with creating 
                                    # lists of same size

newdata = {}
for n, gdf in df.groupby('A'):
    newdata[n]= list(gdf.B.values) + [''] * (maxlen - len(gdf.B)) 

# recreate DF with Col 'A' as index; experiment with other orientations
newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newdict, orient='index') 

# customize this section
newdf.columns = list('BCD')
newdf['A'] = newdf.index
newdf.index = range(len(newdf))
newdf = newdf.reindex_axis(list('ABCD'), axis=1) # to set the desired order

print newdf
```

The result is:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  1  aa        
1  2  bb        
2  3  bb  aa    
3  4  aa  bb  dd
4  5  cc
```